# How to change position of Google Maps infoWindow

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

[image]

As the title says, how can I change the position of an infoWindow like in the image above?

I've followed the instructions from Google. Now I want to change the infowindows position but can't figure out what to do.

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>' +
        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the ' +
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) ' +
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km ' +
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major ' +
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is ' +
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the ' +
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, ' +
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World ' +
        'Heritage Site.</p>' +
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">' +
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> ' +
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `pixelOffset` property.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(200,0)
});
```

See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions

Working code snippet:

```js
function initialize() {

  const mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    map: map,
  });

  const infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Hello world',
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(200, 0)
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script async src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome my friend!

Comment: How to achieve this in angular . I am using agm-info-window

Comment: Open a new question as this is not related to angular.